# JavaScript saving to mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have a loop that saves to mongodb. and sometimes its a bit to fast and I get duplicate error.

I iterate over a object and send each to a check function.

```
import checkExists from './checkExists';

const obj = [
 {name: "Sven", age: 18},
 {name: "Svenie", age: 18},
 {name: "Svenjo", age: 18},
 {name: "Sven", age: 18},
 {name: "Svenja", age: 18},
};

for(let i = 0; i < obj.length: i++){
 checkExists(obj[i]);
}
```

in checkExists I check in mongodb schema if there is a document with the name.

```
import SaveNewUser from './SaveNewUser';

export default async function checkExists(data){
 const {name} = data;
 const amount = await User.find({"name": name}).select("name").lean();

 if(amount.lenght > 0){
    return;
 } else {
    return SaveNewUser(data);
 };
};
```

Then in SaveNewUser I save to database

```
export default function SaveNewUser(data){
 const {name, age} = data;
 const userData = {
    "name": secondary,
    "age": age,
 };

 const saveNewUser = new User(userData);
 saveNewUser.save().then(()=>{
    return;
 }).catch((err)=>{
    console.log(err);
 });
};
```

so, in the start loop there is a double, and it gets send fast to the checkIfExists function. both do not exists yet and get send to the SaveNewUser, where the first will save and the second returns the double error.

this is just an simple example of my code, and there might be more double and I need to check and save data as fast as possible. Does anyone know a good way to make sure I don't get the error?
I could add the checkIfExists function to the save function, but its the same problem.

I am thinking of making a file to save temp data and filter that, but it seems like a ugly solution. I need all functions to be separated in different js files for modular use.

-- Update --

The loop can be executed multiple times from another script with new user object.

Comment: You are passing the value of `i` to `checkExists(i)`.

Comment: No, its obj[i]. just a typo. the code here is not the actual code I use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, here are some weird stuff going on.

First of all i would rename `obj` to something different. Its confusing since its not an object its an array. Like `userArray`

You have the problem that you executing everything at once and not one by one `checkExists` returns an promise. You can await it

import checkExists from './checkExists';

```
const userArray = [
 {name: "Sven", age: 18},
 {name: "Svenie", age: 18},
 {name: "Svenjo", age: 18},
 {name: "Sven", age: 18},
 {name: "Svenja", age: 18},
};

()(async () => {
   for(let i = 0; i < obj.length: i++){
      await checkExists(obj[i]);
   }
})
```

And you have a typo at length

```
import SaveNewUser from './SaveNewUser';

export default async function checkExists(data){
 const {name} = data;
 const users = await User.find({"name": name}).select("name").lean();

 if(users.length > 0){
    return;
 } else {
    return SaveNewUser(data);
 };
};
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. my code is only a example. I can have multiple instances of the 
for loop function running at the same time. and that's where the problem starts.
Its a multiple step system. first request, then check, then save, then get more info, save again and start loop with increment. so the problem is I have the function running twice at the same time without knowing if there is a double in each instance.